# Are old school Martial arts films considered SciFi/Fantasy?

Tags: discussion

When you have people whose skin is indestructible, or who can poke holes in walls with just their fingers, or who can run up walls and seemingly float or fly, would that be considered SciFi/Fantasy? (and, thus, appropriate for the SciFi/Fantasy forum?)

I was trying to connect and old-school Hong Kong movie to Kill Bill, over in the movie forum, but they seem to consider it a simple movie identification question and shot it down.

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/119202/kill-bill-reference-question-what-movie-is-the-basis-of-the-chopstick-wall-att

Then I asked on Scfi/Fantasy, and was told that this is probably the better location

[Are old school Martial arts films considered SciFi/Fantasy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270432/are-old-school-martial-arts-films-considered-scifi-fantasy)

So, I am asking here . . .

Comment: As your original question was migrated to meta and has been answered on meta, I'm closing this one as a duplicate and merging it to get all the answers in one place. Not that you did anything wrong; the community just acted to complete the migration after you'd already posted this second version on meta.